# Dailymotion API/SDK ad break time left

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm using dailymotion API/SDK to launch ad break and edit title etc...
But when i'm launching ads, i'd like to have a callback with time left.

So i can tell to user when ad break is finish.

Can i do that with dailymotion API/SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`live_ad_break_end_time`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-live_ad_break_end_time-field) field for that, be beware that this is only an "estimated time" for the end of the commercial ad break.